# Building boost - build.bat is not recognized as a program

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to build Boost for using the filesystem library.

I understand that I must run bootstrap.bat (for Windows) to create a b2 application, that should I run after.

But I get this errors:

```
C:\Users\Andrei>D:\Info\include\boost_1_58_0\tools\build\bootstrap.bat
Bootstrapping the build engine
The system cannot find the path specified.
'.\build.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Failed to bootstrap the build engine
Please consult bootstrap.log for furter diagnostics.
```

I haven't find build.bat or the log file..

How can I solve this problem ? I read that I must build it to get filesystem libs. It's this true ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should `cd` into the boost build directory before executing bootstrap.bat.

Try

```
cd D:\Info\include\boost_1_58_0\tools\build\
bootstrap.bat
```

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thank you ! So simple .

Comment: I need 15 reputation :( .

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. It's ok like that ?

Comment: I'm using boost_1_66_0, and there are no tools directory...  The folders here are just boost, doc, and libs... Then how to do it?

Comment: @Hzzkygcs try to follow the instruction: https://github.com/boostorg/wiki/wiki/Getting-Started%3A-Overview#installing-boost